# Lowest of array values

Tags: c++

My program is supposed to get random numbers and put them in the array.  Then it's supposed to find lowest, highest, sum, and average.  Everything works except the lowest function.  Any help please!
EDIT: posted whole program

```
  int main()
{
    int nums[SIZE] = { 0 };
    int smallest;
    int highest;
    int sum;
    double avg;

    putNums(nums);
    getNums(nums, SIZE);
    getLowest(nums, SIZE, smallest);
    getHighest(nums, SIZE, highest);
    getSum(nums, SIZE, sum);
    getAvg(nums, SIZE, sum, avg);
    cout << "Smallest number of array: " << nums[smallest] << endl;
    cout << " Highest number of array: " << nums[highest] << endl;
    cout << "Sum of the array: " << sum << endl;
    cout << "Average of the array: " << setprecision(2) << fixed << showpoint << avg << endl;
}
void putNums(int nums[])
{
    ofstream outFil;    // output file object
    string filNam;      // output file name
    srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0))); // seed random number generator  
    int num;            // random number to be generated
    int cnt = 1;        // count of random numbers

    cout << "To generates a file of " << SIZE << " random numbers\n";
    cout << " enter your output file name: ";   // "nums.txt"
    cin >> filNam;
    outFil.open(filNam.c_str());
    if (outFil) {
        for (int k = 0; k < SIZE; ++k) {    // generate and write numbers 
            num = MIN + rand() % MAX;       // generate random number
            cout << cnt << ". " << num << endl;
            outFil << num << endl;
            nums[cnt] = num;
            ++cnt;                          // increment count of numbers
        } // endfor
    }
    else {
        cout << "Open error on file " << filNam << endl;
        exit(1);
    } // endif
    outFil.close();        // close the file
    cout << "\n -- Done - file closed! --\n\n";
}
void getNums(int nums[], int SIZE)
{
    cout << "Your " << SIZE << " number(s) are listed: \n";
    for (int cnt = 1; cnt <= SIZE; cnt++){
        cout << nums[cnt] << endl;
    }
}
int getLowest(int nums[], int size, int & smallest)
{
    smallest = 0;
    int lowest = nums[0];
    for (int cnt = 0; cnt <= SIZE; ++cnt){
        if (nums[cnt] < lowest){
            lowest = nums[cnt];
            smallest = cnt;
        }
    }
    return smallest;
}
int getHighest(int nums[], int SIZE, int & highest)
{
    highest = 0;
    int largest = nums[0];
    for (int cnt = 0; cnt < SIZE; ++cnt){
        if (nums[cnt] > largest){
            largest = nums[cnt];
            highest = cnt;
        }
    }
    return highest;
}
int getSum(int nums[], int size, int & sum)
{
    sum = 0;
    for (int cnt = 0; cnt < SIZE; ++cnt){
        sum += (nums[cnt]);
    }
    return sum;
}
double getAvg(int nums[], int size, int sum, double & avg)
{
    avg = 0;
    avg = static_cast<double>(sum) / SIZE;
    return avg;
}
```

Comment: Why `smallest = cnt + 1` ?

Comment: return lowest, not smallest

Comment: Your API is odd. Why don't you just return the index of the least value.

Comment: You are looping over SIZE+1 values.  Also SIZE != size.

Comment: What exactly isn't working ?

Comment: This has already been invented. It's `std::min_element`.

Comment: To @OP: `int* index = std::min_element(nums, nums + size); smallest = std::distance(nums, index); return *index;`  3 lines, no loops.

Comment: You could do all your calculations in one loop no need for separate functions.

Comment: Part of the assignment is to use them in different functions

Comment: @Jake - Why doesn't your `getAvg` function call `getSum`?  Why are you passing the sum? Let the getAvg figure all of this out.  You should be passing only the data and number of items.  Those other two parameters `sum` and `avg` are basically worthless.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie-Those are working fine.  The getLowest function is just returning it  as 0 every time

Answer (score 1):

You should return the `lowest` variable and not `smallest` due the fact that `smallest` represents the index and `lowest` the value.

It should be:

```
return lowest;
```

Comment: unless he's trying to return the index of the lowest... not sure

Comment: `smallest` (i.e. the index) is already being returned as a reference parameter.

Comment: @markg, He is saying his got a problem with the function, so it is a battle between 2 possible values, he already returning the index, than it leaving us with value, but I got your point.

Comment: @OrelEraki... yes, and if it's the index, he needs to stop +1 in the loop...I was just adding to your answer, not dibuting its validity

Comment: Also stark gave a good answer, he starts with 0 but iterate until <= SIZE he should iterate until < SIZE.

Comment: I'm considering removing my answer, should I ?

Answer (score 1):

The source code is generally good but has conceptual and technical errors, here I send you a solution running

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

#define SIZE 500
#define MIN 1
#define MAX 10000


void putNums(int *nums)
{
    ofstream outFil;    // output file object
    string filNam;      // output file name
    srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0))); // seed random number generator
    int num;            // random number to be generated

    cout << "To generates a file of " << SIZE << " random numbers\n";
    cout << " enter your output file name: ";   // "nums.txt"
    cin >> filNam;
    outFil.open(filNam.c_str());
    if (outFil) {
        for (int k = 0; k < SIZE; k++) {    // generate and write numbers
            num = MIN + rand() % MAX;       // generate random number
            cout << (k + 1) << ". " << num << endl;
            outFil << num << endl;
            nums[k] = num;
        } // endfor
    }
    else {
        cout << "Open error on file " << filNam << endl;
        exit(1);
    } // endif
    outFil.close();        // close the file
    cout << "\n -- Done - file closed! --\n\n";
}
void getNums(int *nums, int size)
{
    cout << "Your " << size << " number(s) are listed: \n";
    for (int cnt = 0; cnt < size; cnt++){
        cout << nums[cnt] << endl;
    }
}
int getLowest(int *nums, int size)
{
    int lowest = nums[0];
    for (int cnt = 1; cnt < size; cnt++){
        if (nums[cnt] < lowest){
            lowest = nums[cnt];
        }
    }
    return lowest;
}
int getHighest(int *nums, int size)
{
    int largest = nums[0];
    for (int cnt = 1; cnt < size; cnt++){
        if (nums[cnt] > largest){
            largest = nums[cnt];
        }
    }
    return largest;
}
int getSum(int *nums, int size)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int cnt = 0; cnt < size; cnt++)
    {
        sum += nums[cnt];
    }
    return sum;
}
double getAvg(int nums[], int size, int sum)
{
    return static_cast<double>(sum) / size;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    int *nums;
    int smallest;
    int highest;
    int sum;
    double avg;

    nums = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * SIZE);
    putNums(nums);
    getNums(nums, SIZE);
    smallest = getLowest(nums, SIZE);
    highest = getHighest(nums, SIZE);
    sum = getSum(nums, SIZE);
    avg = getAvg(nums, SIZE, sum);
    cout << "Smallest number of array: " << smallest << endl;
    cout << " Highest number of array: " << highest << endl;
    cout << "Sum of the array: " << sum << endl;
    cout << "Average of the array: " << fixed << showpoint << avg << endl;
    free(nums);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a memory overwrite in `getLowest`:

```
 for (int cnt = 0; cnt <= SIZE; ++cnt){
```

In the loop, you're accessing `nums[SIZE]` on the last iteration, so you're accessing the array outside of its bounds.

It should be this:

```
  for (int cnt = 0; cnt < SIZE; ++cnt){
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
int getLowest(int nums[])
{
   int lowest = nums[0];
   for(int idx = 0; idx < SIZE; idx++)
   {
      if(nums[idx] < lowest)
         lowest = nums[idx];
   }

   return lowest;
}
```

I'm assuming SIZE is a constant global and you are returning the lowest, so you don't have to pass it by reference